# How to get the styles of any html element from the resolved stylesheets using python?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML with CSS toy example.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
        p {
            font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        .cl0 {
            background-color: coral;
        }
        .cl1 {
            position: absolute;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        p > span {
            color:cyan;
        }
        #id0::before {
            content: "♥";
        }
        #id1::after {
            content: " \21E6";
        }
        .art0 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10em;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="cl1">
        <p class="cl0">
            Story <span id="id0">Numbawan</span>
        </p>
        <article class="art0">
            Story <span id="id1">Numbatu</span>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A browser can process and apply the CSS styles to any element. But is there a way (library) to do the same in python and output something like a BeautifulSoup but with every element having a *property* that would contain its *resolved complete styling*?

```
for span in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(span.string,'--', span.style)
=====================
Numbawan--content: "♥";background-color: coral;font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;color:cyan;
Numbatu--content: " \21E6";position: absolute;left: 10em;
```

And I mean not just for the example above that I can probably hard-code but for any complex styles with numerous style sheets of a modern webpage? I do know there is selenium that under the hood renders the page with chromium but does it allow to see EVERY elements styles the way I described?
I would appreciate any hints how to approach it.

Comment: Beautiful Soup doesn't have a selenium under the hood, as you implied; it is a parser of xml/html docs. But, if you are willing to use selenium and start a browser, what you want to achieve is definitely doable; want help with that?

Comment: I would like to have it programmatically ready, i.e. so that I can go down anywhere in the document tree and have any element with its own CSS properties resolved, i.e. inheritance, default etc. I don't really need BeautifulSoup or anything specific. I just want to be able to have a structure that I can query at will and get the elements with the corresponding properties, similar to what, say, Chrome shows in its styles part but, sort of, simplified.

Comment: So, a browser will still start? Is it possible to use a browser's driver in the background doing all of the heavy-lifting so that I get the document resolved into the python environment in some simplified structure?